# Flutter Riverpod: how to pass multiple arguments in family?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, changenotifier

I can pass one argument along with ProviderScope in Riverpod ChangeNotifierProvider family. But I need to pass more than one/multiple arguments/dependencies.
For example I have to pass context to access other providers value via context.read(provider) and dependencies from UI widget, may be some more also.

Example here:

```
final restaurantProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider.family(
  (ref, BuildContext context, Restaurant? restaurant) => RestaurantNotifier(
    context: context,
    restaurant: restaurant,
  ),
);

class RestaurantNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  RestaurantNotifier(
      {required BuildContext context, required Restaurant? restaurant}) {
    getPlaceMark(restaurant);
    checkIsSaved(context, restaurant!.id);
  }

  getPlaceMark(Restaurant? restaurant) async {
    if (restaurant!.latitude != null && restaurant.longitude != null) {
      List<Placemark> placemarkData = await LocationHelper.getPlaceMark(
        lat: double.tryParse(restaurant.latitude!)!,
        long: double.tryParse(restaurant.longitude!)!,
      );
      placemark = placemarkData[0];
    }
  }

  checkIsSaved(BuildContext context, int? id) {
    final savedRestaurantsId = context.read(savedRestaurantsIdProvider.state);
    isSaved = savedRestaurantsId.contains(id);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/family/#passing-multiple-parameters-to-a-family

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass multiple values into the `Provider` when you create it, you can use the `family` modifier with a custom type.

For example, in this instance, you may want to replace the `String` value with a `Person` value:

```dart
final multipleGreetingProvider = Provider.family<String, Person>(
  (_, person) {
    return "Hello, ${person.name} ${person.surname}!";
  },
);
```

You can now pass a `Person` value into the `Provider` when you create it:

```dart
// prints "Hello, Paul Halliday!"
sayHello(WidgetRef ref) {
  ref.read(
    multipleGreetingProvider(
      Person('Paul', 'Halliday'),
    )
  );
}
```

This can be extended infinitely. If you now have multiple classes you'd like to pass in, you can combine this into a logical unit.

For example, this may look like:

```dart
class Household {
  final List<Person> members;
  final int rooms;

  Household(this.members, this.rooms);
}

final householdProvider = Provider.family<String, Household>(
  (_, household) {
    return "Household has ${household.rooms} rooms and ${household.members.length} members.";
  },
);

// prints "Household has 3 rooms and 1 members."
householdData(WidgetRef ref) {
  ref.read(householdProvider(
    Household(
      [
        Person('Paul', 'Halliday'),
      ],
      3,
    ),
  ));
}
```

This shows how to get around the problem of having to pass in multiple values into the `Provider` using `family`.

[ref](https://developer.school/snippets/flutter/how-to-pass-multilple-values-to-provider-using-family-riverpod).

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot!

Comment: It is critical that your custom class implements the == and hashCode overrides or you could get into an endless rebuild loop, hammering your api or firestore db.
If your classes are marked up using freezed, you're good to go. Otherwise, implement the override bool operator ==(dynamic other) and int get hashCode => Object.hash override methods.

Answer (score 2):

This is another way of providing multiple arguments. Use `List<dynamic>>`

```
final restaurantProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose
.family<RecordModel, List<dynamic>>(
    (ref, args) => ref.read(rsProvider).load(args[0], args[1]));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use typedef with Dart 3. It offers easy and simple use with the family parameter.

```
typedef Parameters= ({String type, int maxPrice});
```

Then you can use provider like this

```
final providerName= FutureProvider.family<Activity, Parameters>((ref, arguments) async {
    .......
});
```

It's pretty simple now

Use it like so:

```
providerName((type: "a", maxPrice: 1));
```

Notice the double parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

If I have to send a list of Strings to the provider, I create a wrapper class to hold the list.

- You have to either properly override the `==` operator or use the `Equatable` package otherwise the provider will keep reloading.

```
class ListWrapper extends Equatable {
  final List<String> items;

  ListWrapper(this.items);

  @override
  // TODO: implement props
  List<Object?> get props => [items];
}
```